# Code that can output changing number to both terminal and file

Tags: c++, file, terminal, cygwin, backspace

I have a c++ program which writes changing numbers to screen, something in the vein of the following snippet:

```
    stringstream ss, ssd; ss << 0; int decs=0; ssd << decs;

    cout << "Number ";

    for(int i=1;i<=1000;i++) {

        cout << ss.str() << "   Decades: " << decs; cout.flush();

        int l=ss.str().length()+12+ssd.str().length(); 
        for(int j=0;j<l;j++) cout << "\b";

        this_thread::sleep_for (chrono::milliseconds(100));

        ss.str(""); ss << i;

        if(i%10==0) {
            decs++; ssd.str(""); ssd << decs;
        }

    }
```

This works fine, but sometimes (not always) I would like to send the output to a file instead of the terminal, using e.g. `./prog > out.txt`. Here the backspace character `\b` doesn't delete character but outputs some symbol (googling tells me this is not surprising).

One option would be to e.g. only output the data at the end of the calculation when printing to a file. But this would entail different code for terminal/file, switching with an input parameter for example. Is there a way I can do this without having separate code for terminal/file output?

I am using cygwin on Windows 7.

Comment: I would use a sleep function or C++11 thread wait rather than doing useless computations :/

Comment: What exactly do you want to write to a file? Give me an example please.

Comment: What is the issue exactly? What do you mean by "backspace doesn't work in the same way"? You should always be able to use `.str` member function of `stringstream` to write both to `cout` and to an `ofstream`

Comment: @Quest The snippet above is an example; my actual program is a Monte Carlo that acquires a number of samples with a (previously unknown) number of "rotations." I want the terminal to display the number of samples acquired and the number of rotations, on a single changing line. I can do this with a terminal but when outputting to a file the backspace causes problems. I'm wondering if it's possible to do this without having separate code for terminal and file output.

Comment: @vsoftco When outputting to a file, instead of deleting a character, `\b` prints (in my case) a black box saying `BS`, funnily enough. Some googling tells me this is not surprising, but I'm wondering if there is a way to do this without having separate code for file and terminal output.

Comment: As I understand, OP wants to have only the final output in his file, whereas he uses `\b` (a non printable character) to *erase* output in terminal.

Comment: After re-reading I though OP wants to "delete" the char in the file, as it works fine in the terminal. Can @jorgen clarify this?

Comment: @vsoftco Yes, "deleting" the char in the file would be one way to do it, if that's possible. But I'm asking more general: if it's possible to have the same piece of code write a "changing line" to terminal or the final output to a file, depending on whether the program is run with `./prog` or `./prog > out.txt`

Comment: A possible workaround may be to use `std::cerr` for intermediate result, and `std::cout` for final result.

Comment: @Jarod42 Brilliant! Thanks a lot, this works. If you write it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible workaround may be to use `std::cerr` for intermediate result (and so for `'\b'`),

and `std::cout` for final result.

Answer (score 2):

Try to write whole string every time and to write just `'\r'` without `'\n'`

```
stringstream ss, ssd; ss << 0; int decs=0; ssd << decs;

for(int i=1;i<=1000;i++) {

    cout << "Number " << ss.str() << "   Decades: " << decs; cout.flush();

    //int l=ss.str().length()+12+ssd.str().length(); 
    //for(int j=0;j<l;j++) cout << "\b";
    cout << '\r';

    this_thread::sleep_for (chrono::milliseconds(100));

    ss.str(""); ss << i;

    if(i%10==0) {
        decs++; ssd.str(""); ssd << decs;
    }

}
```

In this case you'll have the full output in the file.

Comment: Thanks! This works, but as you note I now get the whole thing in the output file and not just the final line. Do you see a way to get the latter?